# Math equation/formula to get quarter based on custom fiscal year end

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Given the calendar year end, which is Dec, we know that Quarter 1 is Jan - Mar, Quarter 2 is Apr - Jun, Quarter 3 is Jul - Sep and Quarter 4 is Oct - Dec.

My question is, is there a formula to get the correct quarter given the Year End (i.e. Apr Year End, Aug Year End, Dec Year End etc) and given the current month, it knows which quarter it'll be.

Below is the table of the quarters based on each month given it's year end.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& Dec\ (Year\ End) & Apr\ (Year\ End) & Aug\ (Year\ End)  \\ \hline
 Jan & Q1 & Q3 &Q2\\ \hline
 Feb  & Q1 & Q4 &Q2\\ \hline
 Mar  & Q1 & Q4 &Q3\\ \hline
 Apr & Q2 & Q4 &Q3\\ \hline
 May  & Q2 & Q1 &Q3\\ \hline
 Jun  & Q2 & Q1 &Q4\\ \hline
 Jul & Q3 & Q1 &Q4\\ \hline
 Aug  & Q3 & Q2 &Q4\\ \hline
 Sep  & Q3 & Q2 &Q1\\ \hline
 Oct  & Q4 & Q2 &Q1\\ \hline
 Nov & Q4 & Q3 &Q1\\ \hline
 Dec  & Q4 & Q3 &Q2\\ \hline
\end{array}

Please note that for Dec Year End, it means that Jan 1st is the start and Dec 31 is the end date.

Apr Year End, means that May 1 is the start and Apr 30th is the Year End.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ take the values $12,4,8$ when the years ends in Dec, Apr and Aug respectively.

Let $n=1,...,12$ index the months Jan,...,Dec.

Then the function $f(x,n)=1+floor[((n-1-x)mod12)/3]$ gives you the number of the quarter the month $n$ is in.

Comment: Hi Evargalo,

Thanks for reply. Is there a way to take 'Dec', 'Apr' and 'Aug' as the numeric month itself, i.e 12, 4 and 8 respectively instead of 0, 1 and 2?

Reason being, I need to incorporate this formula in Excel to get the quarters.

Comment: Yes sure. I'll edit.

Comment: Thanks Evargalo!

Also, my apologies for being stupid here, but am I correct to assume that the value of the floor is then divided by 4, and the remainder is added to 1?

If it's the case, for some reason, I have for n = 12 (Dec) for Dec year end, I have 1 as the quarter.

f(0,12) = 1 +[floor((12-4*0)/3)]mod4
           = 1 + [floor(12/3)mod4
           = 1 + 0
           = 1

Comment: 'mod 4' means that you divide by 4 but you consider the rest, not the quotient. For instance $17 mod 4=1$ because $17=4*4+1$.

Comment: Ok...so my understanding of mod is correct then, that is to take the remainder.

That being said, for Dec year end, and for Dec month, I do get 1 as the value instead of 4.

Is my understanding of the formula wrong then?

Isn't 1 + floor(12/3 = 4)mod4 results in 1+0=1?

Comment: Tried it many times, and it's giving me Dec as Quarter 1 for Dec Year End.

The same with April Year End, for the month of Apr, it's giving me Quarter 1 instead of Quarter 4.

In summary, it's off by 1.

Comment: oh, sorry, I'm sure you have added the '+1' by yourself, but I'll edit and correct my answer.

Comment: Can you check the formula I've just edited and confirm whether the result is appropriate ?